# Qt project a PNG image with varying level of opacity

Tags: qt

Is there a way to project a PNG image on a Qt application with varying levels of opacity? (e.g. values betwene 0.0 and 1.0 where 0.0 is totally invisible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a widget that is on top of all the others you want to overlay.  Draw your image in the [paintEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#paintEvent) function with the desired opacity.

Overlay.h

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPixmap>

class Overlay : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Overlay( QWidget *parent = NULL ) : QWidget( parent ), opacity( 0 )
    {
    }

    void SetPixmap( const Pixmap& p )
    { 
        pixmap = p;
        update();
    }

    void SetOpacity( qreal o )
    { 
        opacity = o;
        update();
    }

protected:
    virtual void paintEvent( QPaintEvent* )
    {
        QPainter paint( this );
        paint.setOpacity( opacity );
        paint.drawPixmap( rect(), pixmap );
    }

private:
    QPixmap pixmap;
    qreal opacity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Image Element is a subclass of Item Element. Item Element has an opacity property.